# sending an email through HTML Form Action

Tags: javascript, html

I am a little confused on how to send an e-mail through

```
 <FORM Action="mailto:michael@microsoft.com?Subject=Hi Michael" METHOD="POST">
```

If I have the following text boxes for input information:

Name
Subject
E-mail Of user
Message

How would I fit all this information into the e-mail being sent? IE: When I open up the email I see:

From: bob@microsoft.com
Subject: Hey
Message: This is the message.

```
   <FORM Action="mailto:you@hotmail.com?Subject=Hi" METHOD="POST">
    <table width="200" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Name </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message</td>
            <td><textarea></textarea></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;<Br></td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="btn1" value="Send!"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually send e-mail via a form action.  You need to send the e-mail server-side.

Comment: so you're saying PHP?

Comment: in which languages can I achieve this? just PHP or ASP?

Comment: @IceDawg, Any server-side language you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send email using javascript or html. You need server side scripts in ASP.NET or other technologies to send email.

> Html by itself will not send email. You will need something that
>   connects to a SMTP server to send an email. Hence Outlook pops up with
>   mailto: else your form goes to the server which has a script that
>   sends email.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP Script to send email and use Jquery Ajax to call the PHP Script from html file..